How to update the content of a div with a button using FastHTML
Using FastHTML, I would like to create a navigation bar that updates a div's content based on the item clicked.
I wrote the following piece of code, but nothing happens when I click the buttons: the #page-content div doesn't update, and I don't see the logs of the GET methods being triggered.
from fasthtml.common import *

app = FastHTML()

@app.route("/", methods=["get"])
def index():
    return Html(
        Body(
            Header(navigation_bar(["page1", "page2"])),
            Div(page1(), id="page-content"),
        ),
    )

def navigation_bar(navigation_items: list[str]):
    return Nav(
        Ul(
            *[
                Li(Button(item, hx_get=f"/{item}", hx_target="#page-content"))
                for item in navigation_items
            ]
        ),
    )

@app.route("/page1", methods=["get"])
def page1():
    return Div("You are on page 1.")

@app.route("/page2", methods=["get"])
def page2():
    return Div("You are on page 2.")

serve()

Here is the generated HTML:
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <button hx-get="/page1" hx-target="#page-content">page-1</button>
          </li>
          <li>
            <button hx-get="/page2" hx-target="#page-content">page-2</button>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <div id="page-content"><div>You are on page 1.</div></div>
  </body>
</html>

I think the HTML is generated correctly, as the tags' attributes related to HTMX look like what I could see on online examples. Where could the issue be?

Hi when you add this  Html(Div("You are on page 1.")) to your py-func what happens? I mean functions page1, page2 and did you add this <script src="https://unpkg.com/htmx.org@1.7.0"></script> to your code.

As Derek mentioned, make sure to include the htmx javascript library in the  section. Your example html does not show htmx included, so maybe that's the issue (ref: https://htmx.org/docs/#installing)

@mariodev spot on , I can't have said it any better.

The issue was indeed related to HTMX not being included. Thank you for your answers!

The issue came from the fact that I was wrapping my Body component into an Html component manually. Removing the Html component, FastHTML takes care of the wrapping automatically and also includes the required scripts.
Here is my updated piece of code:
from fasthtml.common import *

app = FastHTML()

@app.route("/", methods=["get"])
def index():
    return Body(
        Header(navigation_bar(["page1", "page2"])),
        Div(page1(), id="page-content"),
    )

def navigation_bar(navigation_items: list[str]):
    return Nav(
        Ul(
            *[
                Li(Button(item, hx_get=f"/{item}", hx_target="#page-content"))
                for item in navigation_items
            ]
        ),
    )

@app.route("/page1", methods=["get"])
def page1():
    return Div("You are on page 1.")

@app.route("/page2", methods=["get"])
def page2():
    return Div("You are on page 2.")

serve()


Issues
First, I think you want to wrap HTML around your Div
@app.route("/page1", methods=["get"])
def page1():
    return Html(Div("You are on page 1."))

@app.route("/page2", methods=["get"])
def page2():
    return Html(Div("You are on page 2."))


Second, I think you should add this to your html script, apparently without it nothing would happen especially with button clicks
See docs on htmx link -> : htmx
Quotes from the docs
"Htmx is a dependency-free, browser-oriented javascript library. This means that using it is as simple as adding a  tag to your document head. There is no need for a build system to use it."


<head>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/htmx.org@2.0.2" integrity="sha384-Y7hw+L/jvKeWIRRkqWYfPcvVxHzVzn5REgzbawhxAuQGwX1XWe70vji+VSeHOThJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>



